# PHP7 produce error when array push is used on a string

Tags: php-7, strict

How can I configure PHP 7 to produce an error when an item is pushed to a string, for example:

```
$items = '';
$items[] = 'test';
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.6 and 7.0, it is valid to convert a variable containing an empty string into an array like this. Therefore, you will need to provide your own validation to produce an exception.

```php
function checkAndAssign($var, $val){
    if (is_string($var)){
        throw new ErrorException('Do not assign array item to a string');
    }
    return $val;
}

$items = '';

try{
    $items[] = checkAndAssign($items, 'test');
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return;
}

var_dump($items);
```

Results in:

> Do not assign array item to a string

In PHP 7.1 this generates a Fatal Error. There is already a good answer to the question [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error) if you want to attempt that.